creating custom value slider using level-list in android
I want to create a value slider which can got to both -ve and +ve direction from 0 point as shown in below demo image.

I want to achieve this using level-list and I have created the xml as below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <clip android:gravity="left">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:height="2px"
                android:drawable="@drawable/slider_default_track"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            <item>
                <item
                    android:maxLevel="4999"
                    android:minLevel="0">
                    <item
                        android:height="14px"
                        android:gravity="fill">
                        <bitmap
                            android:src="@drawable/custom_track_slider_left"
                            android:tileMode="repeat"
                            android:tint="#FF0000"
                            android:tintMode="multiply" />
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <clip android:gravity="left">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:height="2px"
                android:drawable="@drawable/slider_default_track"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            <item>
                <level-list>
                    <item
                        android:maxLevel="10000"
                        android:minLevel="5000">
                        <item
                            android:height="14px"
                            android:gravity="fill">
                            <bitmap
                                android:src="@drawable/custom_track_slider_right"
                                android:tileMode="repeat"
                                android:tint="#0000FF"
                                android:tintMode="multiply" />
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </level-list>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/zero_mark"
    android:width="5px"
    android:height="12px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:top="7px">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/custom_slider_progress_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>

I tried many possible combinations but either one side of the slider is working properly.
I am getting output like shown below.
1 . When value is at 0 , center black track is completely filled with the custom drawable.

2 .when seeking to negative value, it is looking as below. But this case sliding to right side is working fine.

My requirement is to implement it like, always the center track line should be covered only till the value range with the 2 different drawables. As mentioned in below images.
Requirment 1 . +ve sliding

Requirment 2 . -ve sliding

How can I achieve this by making changes on my existing xml file.
Note: There is no issues with the custom drawable I am using.
Thanks in advance.
